# 301 redirect, windows server

Tags: html, windows, redirect, web, http-status-code-301

Basically, I have changed a number of pages on my site from example.htm to example.html. Now some of these pages have been listed in google for over 11 years and I believe that if i use a 301 redirect it is great for the SEO of the site.

I have tried to configure the web.config and put it straight into the root of the site (as below) but still no success. Can anybody please help, or point out where I am going wrong.

```
<!-- The system.webServer section is required for IIS7 compatability It is ignored by IIS6-->
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="htm to html" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.+).htm$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```